# Javascript !== returning true when should return false

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async.js

I am using a Node.js server and async.js to handle asynchronous callbacks, as well as Mongoose to connect to my Mongo datastore. I am attempting to determine if two object _id's are equal, and if so, execute some code. However, the comparison is not executing correctly. Here's the code:

```
async.forEachSeries(offerItem.offers, function(currentOfferItemOffer, callback) {
    Offer.findById(currentOfferItemOffer, function(err, offerItemOffer) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(offerItemOffer._id) // 56953639ea526c8352081fdd
        console.log(offer._id)          // 56953639ea526c8352081fdd
        if (offerItemOffer._id !== offer._id) {
            console.log('offerItemOffer._id !== offer._id') // Is being logged even though it shouldn't

            ....
```

I am very confused as to why a simple comparison like this would not be executing correctly. The code functions as desired when the two _id's are checked for equality using '===' - but this is incorrect logically, as the next block should only be executed when the _id's are not equal. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: And you're sure you don't really have Mongo objectID's, and not hex strings, did you check those ID's with `typeof`

Comment: Looks like objects, not strings.

Comment: `offerItemOffer._id.toString()` should solve it

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `toString()` method on `_id`.

```
if (offerItemOffer._id.toString() !== offer._id.toString()) {//...
```

`console.log()` calls `toString()` so it seems that output is the same because it is converted to string.

Comment: Yep that did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `_id` are objects, not strings.  In this case they are still two different object.   You should do:

```
JSON.stringify(offerItemOffer._id) !== JSON.stringify(offer.-id)
```

to compare them as strings.

More here [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has two types of inequality operators. Namely `!=` and `!==`.

The `!=` calls stringify upon operators before comparison. That means that the type/class of a given operator isn't taken into account when comparing.

The `!==` doesn't call stringfy. That means that the type/class of an operator is taken into account.

That's why the following sentences produce distinct outputs

```
'1' != 1   // -> false (they are equal since what's being compared is '1' != '1'
'1' !== 1  // -> true  (they are different since what's being compared is a string with an integer)
```

Thus you could fix your problem by ignoring object types/classes by using the `!=` operator.